# double encode php multidimensional array to send to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, multidimensional-array

It is not so much as a problem as I have fixed the issue but I am stuck on the fix, I would like to know why you need to double json_encode a multidimenail array in php when you are returning it to javascript in an ajax call for example.

My Array

```
$jsonData = array('foo', 'bar');
$jsonData['catOne'][] = array('foo two', 'bar two');
```

PHP

```
return json_encode(json_encode($jsonData));
```

Comment: Erm... it is not needed.

Comment: Would you be able to post the output of a single- and double-encoded result?

Comment: well when I do a http request from titanium mobile and use single json_encode it won't load but if I use double it will

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to. The `json_encode` goes through the deepest elements and the json will be perfectly encoded:

```
$arr = array(
    1 => array(5,6,7),
    2 => array(4,3,2),
);

var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

The output for that is:

```
string(25) "{"1":[5,6,7],"2":[4,3,2]}"
```

If you try:

```
var_dump(json_encode(json_encode($arr)));
```

The output will be:

```
string(31) ""{\"1\":[5,6,7],\"2\":[4,3,2]}""
```

See the difference?

Comment: well when I do a http request from titanium mobile and use single json_encode it won't load but if I use double it will